# В чем разнице между Service, Hadler, Proccess в архитектуре бэкенд?

Tags: java, архитектура

Приведу пример из опенсурс приложения

https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/tree/main/modules/flowable-job-service/src/main/java/org/flowable/job/service

Вот, я там увидел три интерфейса:

1. JobService

```
public interface JobService {
    
    void scheduleAsyncJob(JobEntity job);
    
    JobQuery createJobQuery();

    TimerJobQuery createTimerJobQuery();

    SuspendedJobQuery createSuspendedJobQuery();

    DeadLetterJobQuery createDeadLetterJobQuery();
    
    HistoryJobQuery createHistoryJobQuery();
    
    JobEntity findJobById(String jobId);
...
```

2. JobHandler

```
public interface JobHandler {

    String getType();

    void execute(JobEntity job, String configuration, VariableScope variableScope, CommandContext commandContext);
}
```

3. JobProcessor

```
public interface JobProcessor {

    /**
     * Process the given {@link JobProcessorContext}.
     *
     * @param jobProcessorContext the {@link JobProcessorContext} to process
     */
    void process(JobProcessorContext jobProcessorContext);

}
```

Просто если в название есть

- слово `Repository`, то понятно, что это обращение к хранилищу данных
- слово `Mapper или Mapping`, то это сопоставление или отображение данных из одной сущности к другой.

Вопрос, о чем мне должны говорить слова `Service, Hadler, Proccess` в названии интерфейса.

UPD: И что из чего можно вызвать?
Я понимаю, что в `Service` как правило хранится бизнес логика, и там может быть обращение и к `Repository` так и к `Mapper`.
А к чему можно обращаться на уровне `Hadler` и `Proccess`?

Если рекомендуете литературу по данной теме, буду крайне признателен)

Comment: Почему спрашиваете о `Process`, если интерфейс называется `JobProcessor`? `JobHandler` и `JobProcessor` это часть реализации конкретного бизнес домена (в данном случае обработка задач и `JobHandler` содержит как раз код конкретной задачи), это не какая-то общая архитектура бекенд. В другой предметной области их не будет вообще. В сложной предметной области выделили значимые сущности, разделили между ними обязанности, чтоб реализовать требуемое поведение.

Comment: @roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua Если сконфигурировать самый простой проект на `spring boot`, добавить контроллер и сделать запрос. И обратиться к интерфейсу `RequestDispatcher`, то там будут вызываться `Hadler`-ы по очереди. Я не думаю что разработчикам на разных проектах просто слово нравится. Всё таки есть какие-то закономерности

Comment: Закономерность кажущаяся. `Handler` - обработчик. Запрос можно обрабатывать и этим занимается обработчик, и задача в некотором смысле тоже запрос и ее обрабатывает обработчик. Спринг - это инфраструктурный код, приложение - прикладной.  Архитектура фреймворка типа спринг и приложения уровня предприятия (которое внутри может использовать тот же спринг) будут кардинально отличаться, и искать в них сходство нет смысла. Вы спрашиваете о архитектуре прикладного приложения, в известных подходах типа DDD, hexagonal architecture или anemic domain model нет handler-a, а Service, Repository и т.д. есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что написано, то и говорит :
**Service** > это просто один из слоёв архитектуры

Цитата из статьи:

> Сервисный слой (Service layer) — это шаблон проектирования, который
> инкапсулирует бизнес логику вашего приложения и определяет границу и
> набор допустимых операций с точки зрения взаимодействующих с ним
> клиентов.
>
> Думаю, что звучит запутанно и сложно. Если простыми словами, то вы
> сосредотачиваете логику вашего приложения в одном (или нескольких)
> классе-сервисе, а в своих контроллерах обращаетесь к нему. Это
> избавляет от дублирования кода в разных участках системы, делая ваш
> контроллер действительно соответствующим букве S из SOLID.

**Handler** > в переводе "обработчик", видимо должен обрабатывать какое-то событие

**Proccess** > В переводе "процесс", видимо должен запускать выполнение какого-то процесса

Обращаться можно откуда угодно и куда угодно, ЕСЛИ ваш компонент находится на уровень ниже в контексте архитектуры.

Comment: То что из сервиса я могу вызвать репозиторий, это нормально. А из **Hadler** и **Process**? Можно ли вызвать **Hadler** из **Process** и наоборот?

Comment: Можно, но не рекомендуется. Должно идти по нисходящей: **Controller** > **Service** > **и другие менее низкоуровневые** по отношению к бизнес-логики вещи. Если слой **Process** лежит ниже уровня **Service**, то его можно вызывать. Или вообще слой Proccess **должен** вызывается через **Service**, тогда тоже можно, разумеется. Догадываюсь, что **Handler** вызывается не напрямую, а при происхождении какого то события, поэтому его комментировать не буду.

Comment: Если у вас есть какой-то **планировщик заданий** и компоненты **Proccess** создавались для него, то разумеется вызов этих компонентов из слоя сервисов будет нарушением архитектуры, так как **Proccess** классы должны вызываться через **планировщик**.

Comment: Под событиями подразумеваете что-то вроде [event-listener](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) в spirng?

Comment: Это может быть как событие Spring, так и своё собственное событие. Это в целом не важно. Это может быть событие клика мышкой (если разрабатывается Desktop приложении на Java). Класс **Handler** не зависит от контекста.

Comment: Есть ещё много-много всяких суффиксов, которые обычно используют программисты. Есть ещё **Interceptor** http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/04/27/interceptor-perehvat-zaprosov-v-spring-mvc.html. Обычно это суффикс для обозначения классов, которые перехватывают запросы, чтобы как то их обработать.

Comment: Есть ещё **Adapter** и много-много других. Всё это просто нужно для того, чтобы сразу было понятно основное назначение класса. Когда в проекте очень много файлов, это помогает. Можно вообще это в целом не писать (шутка!!! иначе вас выгонят с работы как говно-кодера).